# Accidentally deleted /etc/fstab file

Tags: boot, command-line, fstab

I accidentally deleted my `/etc/fstab` file by running `sudo rm /etc/fstab`. Without realising what I'd done, I shut down my Ubuntu OS.

Now I'm not able to boot.

[image]

My screen looks like this. In some cases, a purple screen appears. Please give me some solutions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to recreate a new `fstab` file inside `/etc` directory and add  an entry for your root partition, so that your Ubuntu os will boot.

### Method 1:

#### Recreating /etc/fstab file via Recovery mode

1. Boot into Recovery mode and then drop to root shell.
2. Run `sudo blkid` command to know the UUID of your `/`(root) partition.It will show something like this,

   ```
   /dev/sda1: UUID="52e062e0-716c-4828-9bf1-05b93fdaef93" TYPE="ext4"
   /dev/sda1: UUID="2F4DAFCF02D7EBEB" TYPE="ntfs" 
   /dev/sda3: UUID="039E0CF305398945" TYPE="ntfs" 
   /dev/sda5: UUID="C68C57908C5779BF" TYPE="ntfs"
   ```
3. From the `sudo blkid` output, identify your root ext4 partition and note down its corresponding UUID.
4. Now mount your `/` partition in Read Write Mode by running the below command.Please note that the simple `mount /` command for mounting your root partition won't work because of the deletion of `/etc/fstab`. So, if your `/` was `/dev/sda1`, run this command:

   ```
   mount -t ext4 -o rw,remount /dev/sda1 /
   ```
5. The above command will mount your `/` partition in read write mode.Run the below command to create a new `fstab` file inside `/etc` with the appropriate line to mount your `/`. In the example above, my `/` has `UUID=52e062e0-716c-4828-9bf1-05b93fdaef93`, so I would run:

   ```
   echo "UUID=52e062e0-716c-4828-9bf1-05b93fdaef93 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1" > /etc/fstab
   ```
6. Exit from the root shell and boot your Ubuntu OS, it will surely bootup.

### Method 2

#### Recreating /etc/fstab file via Ubuntu live disk

1. Boot ubuntu live disk.
2. Run `sudo blkid` command and note the installed Ubuntu partition's device id and the UUID.
3. Mount your root partition,

   ```
    sudo mkdir /media/ubuntu
    sudo mount /dev/sdaX /media/ubuntu
   ```
4. Now go into the `/media/ubuntu` via nautilus and create a `fstab` file inside `/etc`.
5. On that fstab file, add an entry for your root partition like below.

   ```
    UUID=52e062e0-716c-4828-9bf1-05b93fdaef93 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
   ```
6. Save that file.And boot into your installed Ubuntu.

**Note:** My root partition's UUID was given above.Please give your's.After booting into your installed Ubuntu OS, don't forget to add `fstab` entry for your swap partition.

Comment: You shouldn't need to chroot in order to do this. You can write the fstab without it (just mounted) and as it is, it's just going to cause more problems. I'd drop it.

Comment: Method  will not work as you will not be able to drop to a root shell because you are missing fstab. As Oli pointed out, chroot is a bit much and makes repair more complicated then it needs to be. Just boot a live CD, mount the / partition, and write a fstab. You might also wish to include an entry for swap ;) See also - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Comment: @bodhi.zazen i do the first method on maintenance mode.See http://i.stack.imgur.com/KB6Xp.png

Comment: Without fsatb, you will not be able to run bash, you will drop to busy box with limited commands (only what is in the initrd). As with the chroot, sure it is possible, but it is going to be more difficult then simply booting a live image.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen see http://i.stack.imgur.com/2CWDf.png