# Ubuntu Command-line edit /etc/fstab

Tags: 12.04, mount, fstab

I just recover my /etc/fstab file using [THIS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435965/accidentally-deleted-etc-fstab-file)

But after reboot it says:

Mount failed press S to skip and M to mount manually.
on S it skip all services and just start with mount only default drive

on this system /etc/fstab looks like this. which i generated now.

```
UUID=e8008245-01d3-4df3-b409-8036ad7cd0d0 / ext4  default    0     2
UUID=ff122186-e22b-4ba6-a8fc-36ef76150bea / ext4  default    0     2
UUID=81aa6aad-9d95-4f48-aa68-cf2b4a23f4aa / ext4  default    0     2
UUID=7f83f0bf-31b0-4977-97ed-a40d6c8c0c9a / ext4  default    0     2
UUID=4e8e58d8-ef0b-4ebd-8403-8fc81d3121f1 swap
```

what mistake i am doing in above file? What other option do we have to use rather than "Default" or mount except '/'. I have tried doing.

/boot, /, /sda2, /sda1. it give erros like:

- unrecognized mount option "default" or missing value
- mountall: mount /dev/sda5 [725] terminated with status 32
- mountall: filesystem counld not be mounted: /dev/sda5

Running command: `lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,UUID`

```
NAME   FSTYPE UUID
sda
ââsda1 ext4   e8008245-01d3-4df3-b409-8036ad7cd0d0
ââsda2 ext4   ff122186-e22b-4ba6-a8fc-36ef76150bea
ââsda3
ââsda5 swap   4e8e58d8-ef0b-4ebd-8403-8fc81d3121f1
ââsda6 ext4   81aa6aad-9d95-4f48-aa68-cf2b4a23f4aa
ââsda7 ext4   7f83f0bf-31b0-4977-97ed-a40d6c8c0c9a
sr0
```

Comment: The obvious one: You have four different partitions being mounted to the same mount point (and to `/`, at that). I'd guess that at least one of those partitions doesn't exist.

Comment: on `sudo blkid` it shows five UUID drives it means it have four partitions and one swap memory. Do i have to change mount point like `/dev/sda1`,`/dev/sda2`,`/dev/sda3`,`/dev/sda4` ?

Comment: You may have five partitions, but nobody has five partitions mounted on root. Perhaps one of those is an LVM member. What's the output of `sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,UUID`?

Comment: This is the output:
NAME   FSTYPE UUID
sda
ââsda1
ââsda2
ââsda3
ââsda5
ââsda6
ââsda7
sr0

Comment: Now with sudo, Edited

Comment: Interesting. All of them exist and are ext4 partitions. Now try with an fstab containing only one of them (comment out lines of the others). Repeat until you get the right root.

Comment: I know my root directory its: ff122186-

Comment: Ok, then don't mount the other partitions at `/`. Remove their lines, or mount them at other directories, like `/media/something`.

Comment: Do i have to write deafult 0 1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `7f83f0bf-31b0-4977-97ed-a40d6c8c0c9a` is the root partition, mount only it on `/`, so your `fstab` will look like this:

```
UUID=7f83f0bf-31b0-4977-97ed-a40d6c8c0c9a / ext4  errors=remount-ro    0     1
UUID=4e8e58d8-ef0b-4ebd-8403-8fc81d3121f1 swap
```

Ubuntu uses `errors=remount-ro` for `/` by default, and it is helpful in keeping the system running, but preventing future damage, if there disk errors.

And according to [`man fstab`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/fstab):

```
   The sixth field (fs_passno).
          This field is used by the fsck(8) program to determine the order
          in  which  filesystem  checks are done at reboot time.  The root
          filesystem should be specified with a fs_passno of 1, and  other
          filesystems  should have a fs_passno of 2.
```

So the last number should be `1` for `/`.