# I am trying to understand step 6 in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MovingLinuxPartition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, boot-partition

I am trying to copy a partition and make the copy bootable (the original is bootable).  Step 6 of [MovingLinuxPartition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MovingLinuxPartition) refers to something called [instance].  What is that?

Given that one of the consequences of guessing what this means incorrectly is that my computer will become entirely unbootable, I am reluctant to just go blindly guessing.

The "disks" application is actually gnome-disks.  Is there a CLI equivalent for if you are working on a server?

Comment: Note that those older instructions are for MBR (msdos) partitioning which uses MBR for BIOS boot. Newer systems use gpt for UEFI and can use gpt for BIOS boot. But gpt has GUID in partition, primary partition table & backup partition table and GUIDs must all match. So you should not use dd on a partition as duplicate GUIDs not allowed. You may be able to repair with gdisk. http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/ Better to just do new install & restore data, configuration & apps from your normal backup. Also good way to confirm backup has everything as you still have install to recover missing info.

Comment: Have you been satisfied with my answer? Then please give me an upvote (▲). If I could solve your problem, it would be nice if you [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/217657) my answer (✓). In the opposite case, please clarify your needs by [edit]ing or comments. See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

> Step 6 of MovingLinuxPartition refers to something called [instance]. What is that?

The sentence below the command line with [instance] tells you:

> Where [instance] is the version you want to make bootable

When I do `ls -l /usr/lib/grub`, I get just one folder called `i386-pc` which is likely the “instance” you are looking for.

> The "disks" application is actually gnome-disks. Is there a CLI equivalent for if you are working on a server?

Yes but there are *multiple* CLI tools and ways used to do the tasks *integrated* into Disks. The page you are referring to speaks about modifying mount options. This can be done by editing the `/etc/fstab` file manually. If you don’t know how to do it, refer to [similar questions](https://askubuntu.com/q/546274/250300) or [ask a new one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) describing your specific situation.