# Ubuntu 14.? does not start up properly after update

Tags: boot, updates

I fired up my old Ubuntu system and it asked if I wanted to update. I did. When booting up it gave me the red screen and then just the below screen. The computer is a Dell Inspiron 530 that also has Windows Vista as an alternative boot.

```
mount: mounting /dev/loop0 on /root failed: Invalid argument
mount: mounting /dev on /root/dev failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.

Busybox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell(ash)  
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.   

(initramfs) _
```

Comment: Update to -what-? Did you mean -upgrade-?

Comment: It looks like the computer failed to find the root filesystem. Look at any lines that have /dev/sd<something> or /dev/disk/<something> in them. Also, did you do any partitioning or disk swapping before this happened?

Comment: You must do a Recovery-mode boot, type `blkid` to see UUIDs and compare to registered ones at /etc/fstab. Correct them and reboot.

Comment: I meant upgrade.

Comment: I meant upgrade.

Comment: I did no faffing with disks and partitions beforehand. But I have dual-boot with Win Vista.

Comment: I acan't seem to cd to /etc/fstab. Also is the UUID I need for "OS". Others are "MSDOS" and "RECOVERY".(It's a long time since I did Unix in any form...)

Comment: `/etc/fstab` is a file, so you can't `cd` to it :) to read the file run `cat /etc/fstab` or `less /etc/fstab`

Comment: fstab isn't there in /etc.

Comment: hmm... that could be your problem! Let me see if I can find out the easiest way to fix it...

Comment: If the linked questions, including [Accidentally deleted /etc/fstab file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435965/accidentally-deleted-etc-fstab-file), don't enable you to fix this, then please **[edit]** this with details of what you did, what you tried that didn't work, and what happened. Your edit will cause the post to be reviewed for possible reopening. Also, if you comment with `@EliahKagan` I'll see the comment and take a look. I suspect that will fix this for you, though.

Comment: Sorry Eliah, I did method 1 of said post and it didn't work. i get the same failure situation. As stated earlier, used the UUID for "OS". Others are "MSDOS" and "RECOVERY". Should I have been using ext4?